# How can I get the marks from a table in HTML and order it to the right subject with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-table, javascript-objects

I want to programm a gradeaverage calculator. In my Programm you can add a subject and in the subject you can add grades. The grades are in a table. And now I want to calculate the average. But my Problem is that I cant get the value of the table(grades) and then I cant order it to the right subject. The programm should calculate it automatically and show it in the right subject.

Here the important html Part:

```
<ul>
            <div class="subjects">
            <div class = "marks"></div>
            <template id="subject-template">
                <div class="subject-wrapper">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Subject</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input class = "grades" name="mark" type="text" placeholder="grade">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button class="add-mark">Add new mark</button>
                </div>
                <div class="average">
                    <input id = "gradesAverage" placeholder="Your current average:" readonly ="readonly">
                    
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
        </ul>
```

It looks so: [here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQdtE.png)

I hope everyone can help me.

Comment: Can you show html without template and with more than one subject?

Comment: I cant add a picture here. It looks similar. You dont see the white background. You see only the name and the box with the name of the subject

Comment: The problem is that I can't write code for you, because I don't know how the final HTML looks like.

Comment: Should I send you the whole code? But the code is in german. If you'll help me to 100%, I can translate it

Answer (score 0):

You can either make some link between the subject and the marks, for example one will have `data-id` same as the `id` of the other.

Or you can take advantage of DOM and find it using the common ancestor.

```js
function add_mark(btn) {

  var parent = btn.closest(".subject-wrapper-wrapper")
  var input = parent.querySelector("[name=mark]");
  var output = parent.querySelector("#gradesAverage");

  var number = +input.value;

  // calculate average
  var avg = 12 + number;

  output.value = avg;


}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="subjects">
    <div class="marks"></div>


    <div class="subject-wrapper-wrapper">
      <div class="subject-wrapper">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Subject</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input class="grades" name="mark" type="text" placeholder="grade">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="add-mark" onclick="add_mark(this)">Add new mark</button>
      </div>
      <div class="average">
        <input id="gradesAverage" placeholder="Your current average:" readonly="readonly">

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</ul>
```